# Upload a folder with more than one app to github with git

Tags: git, github

I had 3 directories monitored by git and 1 that wasn't monitored. I wanted to make a copy from all of them and paste them in a larger separate directory and push them to github with. Unfortunately it didn't work. Only the unmonitored folder was uploaded and for the others I see only the name and a green icon. Can someone help me do the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

When you `git add` a directory to a git repository that is a git repo itself (includes a `.git` folder), then git adds it as a [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).
This will only include the revision of the submodule, rather than the files in that directory.

See also this SO: [how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule).
If you removed the submodule and the `.git` folder (in the export!) you can add the folder again.
This time it should be the complete folder.

---

You should also consider if submodules are already a solution to your problem.